# How to limit hotspot's client of an Android?

Tags: wifi-hotspot, mac-address

I would like to make an Android device as hotspot. I will put it in my roof so it will receive vetther signal, and turn in its hotspot. I want to make that hotspot accessable by certain devices only by register their MAC adress at the hotspot device.

How can I do it? I don't see any option in the hotspot setting so I can do it.

Comment: Android uses `dnsmasq` as DHCP server to assign IP addresses to connected devices. You can create `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` and ignore certain MAC addresses, assign fixed IP for certain MAC addresses,  limit the range of IP addresses etc.

Comment: I will use that hotspot in an office, which some people with mobile device will be used to access i ternet. So I will allow certain people only to access. But however, those people will come and go. If I have to assign the IP, will be very uneffective. So, limiting the access by MAC is the best.

Comment: Yeah you can do that with [dnsmasq.conf](https://github.com/imp/dnsmasq/blob/master/dnsmasq.conf.example#L226), but you need root access to modify `/system` partition. Also, Android doesn't use `dnsmasq.conf` by default, instead all options are provided on commandline. So you might need to replace `/system/bin/dnsmasq` binary with a custom shell script to modify those options because those are hard-coded in [netd](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/netd/+/android-9.0.0_r33/server/TetherController.cpp#217) when building ROM.